# prevent duplicate celery logging

Tags: python, logging, celery

How do I prevent duplicate celery logs in an application like this?

```
# test.py
from celery import Celery

import logging

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')
app.logger = logging.getLogger("new_logger")
file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("app.log", maxBytes=1024*1024, backupCount=1)
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('custom_format %(message)s'))
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

@app.task
def foo(x, y):
    app.logger.info("log info from foo")
```

I start the application with: `celery -A test worker --loglevel=info --logfile celery.log`

Then I cause foo to be run with `python -c "from test import foo; print foo.delay(4, 4)"`

This results in the "log info from foo" being displayed in both `celery.log` and `app.log`.

Here is app.log contents:

```
custom_format log info from foo
```

And here is celery.log contents:

```
[2017-07-26 21:17:24,962: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0
[2017-07-26 21:17:24,967: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-07-26 21:17:25,979: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-07-26 21:17:25,991: INFO/MainProcess] celery@jd-t430 ready.
[2017-07-26 21:17:38,224: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: test.foo[e2c5e6aa-0d2d-4a16-978c-388a5e3cf162]  
[2017-07-26 21:17:38,225: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] log info from foo
[2017-07-26 21:17:38,226: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-4] Task test.foo[e2c5e6aa-0d2d-4a16-978c-388a5e3cf162] succeeded in 0.000783085000876s: None
```

I considered removing the custom logger handler from the python code, but I don't want to just use celery.log because it doesn't support rotating files.  I considered starting celery with `--logfile /dev/null` but then I would loose the mingle and other logs that don't show up in `app.log`.

Can I prevent "log info from foo" from showing up in `celery.log`?  Given that I created the logger from scratch and only setup logging to `app.log` why is "log info from foo" showing up in `celery.log` anyway?

Is it possible to get the celery MainProcess and Worker logs (e.g. `Connected to redis://localhost:6379/0`) to be logged by a RotatingFileHandler (e.g. go in my `app.log`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why is "log info from foo" showing up in celery.log?

The logging system is basically a tree of `logging.Logger` objects with main `logging.Logger` in the root of the tree (you get the root with call `logging.getLogger()` without parameters).

When you call `logging.getLogger("child")` you get reference to the `logging.Logger` processing the "child" logs. The problem is when you call `logging.getLogger("child").info()` the info message is delivered to the "child" but also to the parent of the "child" and to its parent until it arrives to the root.

To avoid sending logs to the parent you have to setup the `logging.getLogger("child").propagate = False`.

Comment: This was such a simple solution that took me way too long to find. Thank you!

Comment: This was the only thing I have found that works right. 

One thing I noticed using this method is if you set your celery workers to loglevel info (or w/e you set your logger too) neither of them will log.